# Separate text in one cell that is stacked into their own fields in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried to use the text to columns feature in Excel to separate stacked data in an Excel cell but it won't work. Just leaves me with the first number and the others are deleted. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

So, cell A is my current data. This also could contain more than 3 entries. I want to display the data across B1, C1, D1 etc.

Also, when using fixed width (which is not ideal as data is not so uniform) in this example, leaves me with spaces in some cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A VBA option using a UDF:

```
Option Explicit

Function V_split(P1 As Range, ID As Integer)
    V_split = Application.Index(Split(P1, Chr(10)), ID)
End Function
```

[image]

If you are only dealing with numbers and want to perform operations with it, just add `*1` to the formula as `=V_split($A1,COLUMN()-1)*1`